# Automate taking a screenshot of specified area

Tags: applescript, automator, screen-capture

I am trying to use automator to take a screen shot of a specified area. Though I can only find the option of taking a screenshot of a windows or the entire screen. Is there a option to to this with automator or with apple script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`screencapture` has a `-R` option for specifying the area. It is not mentioned in the man page but it is mentioned in the help message:

```
$ screencapture -h
screencapture: illegal option -- h
usage: screencapture [-icMPmwsWxSCUtoa] [files]
  -c         force screen capture to go to the clipboard
  -C         capture the cursor as well as the screen. only in non-interactive modes
  -d         display errors to the user graphically
  -i         capture screen interactively, by selection or window
               control key - causes screen shot to go to clipboard
               space key   - toggle between mouse selection and
                             window selection modes
               escape key  - cancels interactive screen shot
  -m         only capture the main monitor, undefined if -i is set
  -M         screen capture output will go to a new Mail message
  -o         in window capture mode, do not capture the shadow of the window
  -P         screen capture output will open in Preview
  -s         only allow mouse selection mode
  -S         in window capture mode, capture the screen not the window
  -t<format> image format to create, default is png (other options include pdf, jpg, tiff and other formats)
  -T<seconds> Take the picture after a delay of <seconds>, default is 5
  -w         only allow window selection mode
  -W         start interaction in window selection mode
  -x         do not play sounds
  -a         do not include windows attached to selected windows
  -r         do not add dpi meta data to image
  -l<windowid> capture this windowsid
  -R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect
  files   where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen
```

Answer (score 3):

[**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can do this using the following macro ([download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4lzvwiha7wp0wqz/Screen%20Capture.kmmacros)):

[image]

Comment: When I attempt this, I am notified that the file can't be written: https://i.imgur.com/5KyU4cQ.png